# .NET WEB API Open an image file in to a new browser tab by using FTP

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, ftp

I have an function that use FTP protocol to download an Image from the other site. But now i want to open it into a new tab, not downloading it. Here is my C# code to download it. Thanks for reading

```
byte[] byteFTP = ftpclass.ReadFTPFile(results, ConfigCache.HostURL, ConfigCache.UserName, ConfigCache.Password);
if (byteFTP != null)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    var dataStream = new MemoryStream(byteFTP);
    response.Content = new StreamContent(dataStream);
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = results;
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
    response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = dataStream.Length;
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly choose to force a new tab open from the server side. You can of course include some JavaScript code that tries to open the new tab<sup>1</sup>, but there's an issue. Have you heard of pop-up ads? Having JavaScript arbitrarily opening new windows *not* in response to user interaction is increasingly locked down in browsers.

So, instead you need to open that new tab (client side) when the user performs whatever interaction it is that *the code in your question is running in response to*. Then your server code has nothing to do - you've already given it a new tab to deliver your response into normally (And can remove the `ContentDisposition` related code now - you may also want to provide a more specific content type)

---

<sup>1</sup>And ignoring the rest of the issues, you would have to make your response contain *that JavaScript* and not the image any more.

Answer (score 0):

To allow a file to be viewed in a new tab you should set the [Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header to `"inline"`. However, depending on the file type, this can still be decided by the browser. Inline just means that an *attempt* will be made to display it, before falling back to downloading